# stack depth limit exceeded when fired a trigger

Tags: postgresql, database-trigger

I am trying to build a slow changing dimensional table, it track all the history of records. The schema of the table is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test.dim
(id text,
 column1 text,
 column2 text,
 begin_date timestamp without time zone,
 is_current boolean,
 end_date timestamp without time zone)
```

I defined a trigger function, and fire it before each insert action:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test.slow_change_func()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
  DECLARE
    BEGIN
        IF ( NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM yang_test.dim
                          WHERE id= NEW.id  
                                AND(column1 = NEW.column1 OR (column1 is null AND NEW.column1 is null))
                                AND (column2 = NEW.column2 OR (column2 is null AND NEW.column2 is null))
                                AND is_current
                          )
            )
        THEN  UPDATE yang_test.dim
               SET (end_date, is_current) = (now(), FALSE)
               WHERE id = NEW.id
                        AND is_current;
               INSERT INTO test.dim (id, column1, column2, begin_date, is_current, end_date)
               VALUES ( NEW.id, NEW.column1, NEW.column2, now(), TRUE, 'infinity'::timestamp );

         END IF;
      RETURN NULL;
    END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;





CREATE TRIGGER slow_change_trigger
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON test.dim
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE test.slow_change_func();
```

When I try to test it,

```
INSERT INTO test.dim (id, column1, column2, begin_date, is_current, end_date)
               VALUES ( 1, 'hello', 'world', now(), TRUE, 'infinity'::timestamp )
```

it will throw an error:  stack depth limit exceeded. it looks like the function is running a loop. any suggestion s?

Comment: Your insert trigger inserts into the database so it will be triggered over and over again. And it seems to do it with the same values as already were inserted by the first one. Is that really what you mean?

Comment: thanks for your explanation. How to prevent it? I certainly just want the trigger function fired once before an insert statement. thanks

Comment: If you remove the insert inside the trigger it shouldn’t happen. But is there a reason for it being there, like you’d want to cancel the insert in some situation?

Comment: I don't want every row insert into the table. If the new row is already in the table (same id, column1,column2 values), then do nothing; otherwise, update the old rows in the table and insert the new row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have figure this out, this will match my requirement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION yang_test.slow_change_func()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
  DECLARE
    BEGIN
        IF ( NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM yang_test.dim
                          WHERE id= NEW.id  
                                AND(column1 = NEW.column1 OR (column1 is null AND NEW.column1 is null))
                                AND (column2 = NEW.column2 OR (column2 is null AND NEW.column2 is null))
                                AND is_current
                          )
            )
        THEN  UPDATE yang_test.dim
               SET (end_date, is_current) = (now(), FALSE)
               WHERE id = NEW.id
                        AND is_current;
        ELSE RETURN null;


         END IF;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```